# Http Pattern for Batch Delete that takes a long time

Tags: rest, http

How should I structure a Delete endpoint where the delete takes a long time.

In my application, I store a bunch of ids and have prefix batch endpoints. So for example: `GET /prefix/{prefix}` returns all ids matching `{prefix}`. I want to implement a similar `DELETE` endpoint. Right now, I return a `Response` success or failure when I'm done.

However the deleting can take too long and the socket with the client times out leaving the delete in a broken or incomplete state.

My thought to avoid this is to simply return a response before actually doing the delete. But I'm curious what the right way to design this is. (i.e. what should the return be? Is this an ok model? etc) We can call the endpoint "attempt delete" instead of an actual delete, because there is no guarantee that it will succeed and no message if it fails.

Requirements:

- The client should have a way to know when the delete has finished
- The delete should continue even if the client disconnects
- I don't need reliability. That is to say, if a client says `DELETE xyz` and then `GET xyz` its ok for the second request to return objects that have not yet been deleted. The only guarantee is that once the `DELETE` completes, doing a `GET` on the resource will throw an error.

(FWIW I'm using java and jersey but that shouldnt matter)

Answer (score 1):

> How should I structure a Delete endpoint where the delete takes a long time.

I would expect that you handle it in an analogous way to any other request that takes a long time: [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3)

> The 202 (Accepted) status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
>
> The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

If you think of the delete operation as a task that is running, and that task logs its progress, then the "log of task #X" resource is the thing that tells the client how it is going.

> In my application, I store a bunch of ids and have prefix batch endpoints. So for example: GET /prefix/{prefix} returns all ids matching {prefix}. I want to implement a similar DELETE endpoint.

[DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) might not be the right method to use in this case.

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server remove the association between the target resource and its current functionality.  In effect, this method is similar to the rm command in UNIX: it expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping of the origin server rather than an expectation that the previously associated information be deleted.
>
> ... Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect.

That's not really a good match, semantically, for "put a task in the queue that tombstones a bunch of entities".

The same idea, with a different spelling: the request

```
DELETE /prefix/xyzzy ...
```

Means "remove the capability to retrieve the collection-of-ids-with-prefix-xyzzy", not "make the collection-of-ids-with-prefix-xyzzy empty".

Keep in mind, the point of a REST API is to make your domain look like everything else on the web; it's an adapter (in the [Gang of Four](http://a.co/gnNKcsc) sense) that from the outside looks like a website, but on the inside is intimately familiar with your own service.

Fielding, in his thesis, wrote

> REST enables intermediate processing by constraining messages to be self-descriptive: interaction is stateless between requests, standard methods and media types are used to indicate semantics and exchange information, and responses explicitly indicate cacheability -- [Section 5.3.1](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_3_1)
>
> Within REST, intermediary components can actively transform the content of messages because the messages are self-descriptive and their semantics are visible to intermediaries -- [Section 5.1.6](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)

Now, truth be told, the REST police are too busy complaining that you aren't using hypermedia, and nobody else cares.  It's not particularly likely that anyone is going to be trying to use your API with a generic remote authoring client, and cache-invalidation is one of the [two hard problems](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) even if you are using HTTP DELETE semantics.  So you are likely to get away with it.

But a REST API to modify a set of domain entities would usually look like the *creation* of a (short lived) resource that describes which entities should be modified.  This about how you would achieve this same result with a web browser and HTML: You would GET this prefix resource, and accompanying the representation of the ids would be a link saying "Do you want to delete these? click HERE", and getting that link would load up a form, describing the ids to be modified.  The form would have a POST action (announcing to the intermediary components that this is not a [safe operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)).  Submitting the form would append a message to a queue, and return a link to the progress meter as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my opinion, help it will be helpful :)

Since the HTTP protocol has the DELETE in the [RFC standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) using DELETE Request method is a good idea. However, http has its limitation that it cannot take a action from a server side thus the only way to take a response is periodic checking from client or taking a response.

If I were you, I will do like this.

- Server will attempt to delete when took a response, and server will response immdeidately
- response has a state such as granted, denied, and unable (hasn't have files) with the number of matching files (i.e. 0)
- Server will do delete the files and ready to response the number of left files (If not, searching the number of matching files with different processes independently also okay)
- Client will periodically send a checking request and took a response from the server with Ajax or something with protocol such as GET alike method to take a number of left files
- Otherwise, if you want to use more complex system, you can took a key from the server and call a request with key to take a status of deleting. However, it depends on what services are you planning to.

Most of the cases will be okay with the method. For example, if two clients sends the same delete actions, there would be no conflict between two actions but actually deleting files.

Good Luck